# Como consigo fazer essa comparação entre os dados da mesma coluna?

Tags: sql, postgresql, funções

"Crie uma função (intitulada fn_bo_varios_estados) que receba como parâmetro o código (INTEGER) de
uma vítima e retorne (TRUE ou FALSE) se ela já registrou boletins de ocorrência em mais de um estado do território
brasileiro."

Como consigo fazer essa comparação entre os dados da mesma coluna?

No caso de retornar TRUE ou FALSE, eu teria que printar como mensagem? Como faço isso?

Answer (score 1):

Bom pelo que entendi de sua pergunta elaborei algo para tentar de ajudar. Porém eu fiz em PL/SQL utilizando Oracle, no caso como você está utilizando Postgresql as vezes você precise alterar alguma coisa na sintaxe, mas é só seguir a lógica. Bom vamos lá...

Criei uma tabela **vitima**, nela possuo idBoletim, idVitima e estado. Criei ela somente para testar se iria funcionar.

```
create table vitima(
    idBo integer primary key,
    idvitima integer not null,
    estado varchar(3) not null
)
```

Povoei a tabela:

```
 insert into vitima values(12,1,'mg');
 insert into vitima values(13,1,'mg');
 insert into vitima values(14,1,'mg');
 insert into vitima values(16,1,'mg');
```

Agora está é a função que criei para verificar se tal id da vitima possui boletins registrados em diferentes estados.

```
create or replace function f_bo_varios_estados (p_idVitima in vitima.idvitima%type)
return boolean as 
        v_status boolean;
        v_cont int;
begin 
        select count(distinct estado) into v_cont from vitima where idvitima = p_idVitima;

        if (v_cont != 1) then
              v_status := true;
              return v_status;
        else 
              v_status := false;
              return v_status;
        end if;

end;
```

E por fim, um bloco para testar a função, eu coloquei a mensagem neste bloco, porém nada impede que tu coloque para imprimir a mensagem dentro da função.
Lembrando que para imprimir mensagem na tela precisa utilizar este comando:
`set serveroutput on;` no Oracle, não me lembro se precisa no postgres também.

```
DECLARE
     status boolean;
BEGIN 
     status := f_bo_varios_estados(1);
     if(status = true)then
          dbms_output.put_line('Vitima registrou boletim em mais de 1 estado');
     else
          dbms_output.put_line('Vitima registrou boletim em 1 estado');
     end if;
END;
```

Pronto! De acordo com a maneira que povoei a tabela lá no inicio, o output será:

`Vitima registrou boletim em 1 estado
Procedimento PL/SQL concluído com sucesso.`

Caso contrário, output:

`Vitima registrou boletim em mais de 1 estado
Procedimento PL/SQL concluído com sucesso.`

Comment: Muito obrigado, man, era exatamente isso. Valeu mesmo! (não consigo votar na resposta, pois ainda não tenho 15 de reputação, desculpe)

Comment: @SimonBlack que bom que te ajudou! depois aceite ela como resposta! abraço